# Is there a better way to validate checkbox selection Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have an angular material stepper, on the first step of the stepper I will show the user a list of 'deliveries' which they can select, I want to validate that at least one delivery was checked before they can move to the next step. On the second step of the stepper it will display 'drivers' to select and will go through the same validation process, so at least one driver was selected. I have come up with a solution however I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve the same desired outcomes.

How my solution works:

I have the following variables,

```
deliveryValidator: number;
deliveryNext: boolean;
```

I set those varibales on init to the following,

```
this.deliveryValidator = 0;
this.deliveryNext = true;
```

In my html I have a `mat-checkbox` which will call a method on change,

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="onDriverSelect($event)">Select</mat-checkbox>
```

The method will then check if the checkbox is being checked or unchecked and will either plus one or subtract one from the `deliveryValidator` variable and will then based on that set the `deliveryNext` to true or false so if `deliveryValidator = 0` then `deliveryNext = true` and vice versa,

```
 onDeliverySelect(event: MatCheckboxChange) {
    if (event.checked) {
      this.deliveryValidator += 1;
    } else {
      this.deliveryValidator -= 1;
    }

    if (this.deliveryValidator > 0) {
      this.deliveryNext = false;
    } else {
      this.deliveryNext = true;
    }
  }
```

The button to navigate to the next step will then either be enabled or disabled based on the value of `deliveryNext`,

```
<button mat-button matStepperNext [disabled]="driverNext">Next</button>
```

The same logic applies to the delivery selection but with its own variables and method.

I hope I have explained myself properly. I am fairly new to angular and I am not sure if there is a better way of going about this, any pointers will be greatly appreciated :)

Versions:

- *Angular CLI: 11.2.13*
- *Angular: 11.2.14*
- *Angular Material: 11.2.13*

Comment: the first you need is understand a few Angular. Angular is only relation "variables" (defined in .ts) with the .html, so if a variable `name` get a value of "Hello", you can show in html using `{{variable}}`. So you need decided where you want to "store" the drivers and delivers. You can use template driven form (using simple variables and `[(ngModel)]`) or Reactive forms (some more complex but more powerfull using `formGroup` and formControls)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have some `deliveries` and `drivers` array. If you give `Driver` and `Delivery` the same structure you can do:

```
@Component({/*...*/}) class YourComponent {

   valid: boolean;
   current: Array<Driver|Delivery>;
   private deliveries: Driver[];
   private drivers: Delivery[];

   ngOnInit() {
     this.current = this.deliveries;
   }

   validate() {
     this.valid = this.current.some(c => c.selected);
   }
}


<mat-checkbox *ngFor="let x of current" [(ngModel)]="x.selected"
              (ngModelChange)="validate()">
   {{ x.name }}
</mat-checkbox>
```